# How to point configure down the right path to icu

Tags: macos, configuration, terminal, icu

I'm a newcomer to macs and terminal in particular, so this may be a stupid question.  I'm trying to run ./configure in mysrc/myfreeling so that I can install freeling but I get this error: 
checking for main in -licuuc... no

Unicode ICU library not found.
   Make sure libicu is
   installed and can be found in a standard path.
   You may need to set LDFLAGS to specify search path.
Now, when I do "port installed" it shows:
icu @49.1.2_0 (active)
So I know that I have icu.  So I tried env LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib" and env LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib/icu" which is where the icu folder is located, but I still get the same error.  How can I tell configure how to access icu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it working.  I had installed icu with MacPorts.  I just went and did a manual install and now its working.  I'm not sure why/how this resolved the issue and would love to know if anyone has any insight.