# Can't install php Intl extension on MacosX

Tags: php, terminal, macos-high-sierra, intl

I'm following this [link](https://pagegwood.com/web-development/how-to-enable-intl-extension-mamp-osx-10-9-2/#%F0%9F%8C%B4) to install this PHP extension but I'm stuck in the middle.
When I try to run this command `pecl install intl` I get this message:

```
Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] :
```

And I don't know where the ICU libraries are located.
If I press Enter I get this error:

```
configure: error: Unable to detect ICU prefix or no failed. Please verify ICU install prefix and make sure icu-config works.
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/intl/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=DEFAULT' failed
```

How can I locate the correct path of ICU libraries ?
I'm using High Sierra and MAMP with PHP version 7.1

Comment: It might work using `brew` like described in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085083/install-php-intl-extension-on-macos/

Comment: I have tried this but still not working, you see I was trying to install `PayumBundle` for symfony and it requires this extension

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ICU stands for *ICU - International Components for Unicode*

Install it with brew

```
brew update
brew search icu # returns 'icu4c'
brew install icu4c
```

OR

Install it with pecl

```
sudo pecl update-channels
sudo pecl install intl
```

[installing intl package on osx](http://darraghenright.tumblr.com/post/22027208929/installing-intl-package-on-osx-lion)

Comment: Thanks for your response but it still ask me to enter icu path whenever I try to use `sudo pecl install intl`

Comment: What about the first method, with brew ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726386/how-to-point-configure-down-the-right-path-to-icu

Comment: Yes I found the path from the link you provide, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have come across the same. Brew install icu4c seems to work but sudo pecl install intl fails. It is trying to install in the default directory. Get ERROR: `make' failed.  Still getting 'Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators).'

Comment: Perfect. Don't hesitate to upvote if the answer has helped you.

Comment: @dan Installing `php56-intl` for `php 7.1`?  If I try to install php56-intl I get this error : `Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Comment: `sudo pecl install intl` .command returns  `configure: error: Unable to detect ICU prefix or no failed. Please verify ICU install prefix and make sure icu-config works.
ERROR: "/private/tmp/pear/install/intl/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=DEFAULT' failed"`

Comment: `sudo pecl install intl` for `php 7.3` returning error: 
`In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.h:34:
/private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/intl_error.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ext/standard/php_smart_str.h' file not found
#include <ext/standard/php_smart_str.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed`

Comment: `make` is still failing on me just like for @Shankar. Were you able to solve it mate?

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: after a better look in php@5.6 it seems that it is already compiled with 'intl'

```
php -i | grep intl
... '--enable-intl' ...
```

So my answer is normally useless for php@5.6 (but can be useful in some cases I guess)

---

I'm facing the same issue today trying to switch from php56 to php@5.6.

After lot of digging, here is the workaround.

Make sure to have a clean install of php@5.6 and to have it at the current version

```
php -v
PHP 5.6.35 (cli) (built: Mar 31 2018 20:21:31)
```

Make also sure to have icu4c

```
brew update
brew install icu4c
```

Next, we will install and compile intl manually

```
cd /usr/local/src/
wget https://pecl.php.net/get/intl-3.0.0.tg
tar zxf intl-3.0.0.tgz
cd intl-3.0.0/
phpize --clean
phpize
./configure
```

And here is the trick, edit Makefile

```
vi Makefile
```

Modify the line `CXXFLAGS` as follow

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -std=c++11
```

AND the line `CPPFLAGS` as follow

```
CPPFLAGS = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=1
```

Next, save, and compile

```
make
make install
```

And voila

```
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.35/pecl/20131226/
```

Don't forget to add `extension="intl.so"` to your php.ini

```
vi /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
```

(and to restart apache)

Sources:

- https://gist.github.com/redefinelab/4188331
- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/commit/d7a3e0b6487780e0d983b35b8f42aad0fd01bf78

Answer (score 4):

download the version of PHP you use in XAMPP from php.net. I am using 7.3. This version worked for me: php-7.3,
I’m guessing if you follow the steps it might work for 7.0 or 7.2 as well.

Extract the tar.gz file using (I extracted it inside ~/Downloads/ folder )

tar -xzvf php-7.1.31.tar.gz
cd into the extracted folder

cd php-7.1.31
change to subfolder ext/intl

cd ext/intl/
Run these commands to build the extension

/Applications/XAMPP/bin/phpize

./configure --enable-intl --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/

make

sudo make install

you can now delete all files you downloaded and also the extracted folders.

Open /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini , and add extension=intl.so

That’s it! Restart your Apache using XAMPP GUI and it should work. You have to run these commands each time you install a new version of XAMPP.

Comment: Awesome, you saved my day! Thank you very much, sir

Comment: A quick note, you need to install autoconf first (brew install autoconf)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me with XAMPP and PHP 7.3